# MassTransit Azure Service Bus - Consuming faults using Topics/Subscriptions

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I am currently testing out MassTransit exception handling, and am struggling to get Fault messages published. Ideally I'd
like a Subscription consumer to retry and then if a fault is thrown, have another consumer pick this up, so far I have a
simple setup:

1. A test consumer with retry definition:

```
public class TestConsumer : IConsumer<MyEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyEvent> context)
    {
        throw new Exception("Whoops");
    }
}

public class TestConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<TestConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<TestConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        base.ConfigureConsumer(endpointConfigurator, consumerConfigurator);
        consumerConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(configureRetry => configureRetry.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    }
```

2. A fault consumer:

```
public class TestFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<MyEvent>>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<MyEvent>> context)
    {
        return; // Handle something here
    }
}
```

Registered as follows:

```
services.AddMassTransit(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
        {
            busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer<TestConsumer, TestConsumerDefinition>();
            busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer<TestFaultConsumer>();

            busRegistrationConfigurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((busRegistrationContext, serviceBusFactoryConfigurator) =>
            {
                serviceBusFactoryConfigurator.Host(configuration["ServiceBusSettings:ConnectionString"]);

                serviceBusFactoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint("test-consumer", "my-topic", cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(busRegistrationContext);
                });
            });
        });
```

When the exception is thrown in the first consumer, there is no fault queue created in ASB. Is there a piece of setup I am
missing to configure the error queue in ASB and have the Fault be consumed?

Also as a final aside, I'd also like to get this Fault consumption working within an Azure function, is this possible or is this not supported with ASB/Functions?

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your consumer definition should be configuring retry on the endpoint, not the consumer:

```cs
public class TestConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<TestConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<TestConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(configureRetry => configureRetry.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    }
}
```

Second, you aren't calling `ConfigureEndpoints`, so there won't be an endpoint created for the fault consumer as it isn't configured. You should configure it *after* the subscription endpoint is configured:

```cs
busRegistrationConfigurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((busRegistrationContext, serviceBusFactoryConfigurator) =>
{    serviceBusFactoryConfigurator.Host(configuration["ServiceBusSettings:ConnectionString"]);

    serviceBusFactoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint("test-consumer", "my-topic", cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<TestConsumer>(busRegistrationContext);
    });

    serviceBusFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(busRegistrationContext);
});
```

As to the part about Azure Functions, that would require configuring everything in Azure Service Bus manually, since AF is the transport and requires everything to exist up front. There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction), that might give you some guidance.

> I am *not* a fan of Azure Functions, as I find the deployment model painful, but it is supported by MassTransit.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the swift reply. I thought that the UseMessageRetry configured at the consumer level would mean I could have separate retry policies for each consumer. (I avoided configuring it on the Receive endpoint itself just in case configuring it across two consumers would have unpredictable effects). Are there any scenarios where we would configure on the consumer (As the methods are exposed to both)?

Comment: In modern times? No, since typically consumers have scoped dependencies that break on retry such as `DbContext`. But if it's purely just to retry the `Consume` method with the same consumer instance, it can be configured as you had done previously.